# How to calculate time for two different actions in JMeter Webdriver sampler

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I want to log the time for two different actions in the JMeter webdriver sampler.
The issue i am facing is, it is logging the same time for both. Here is my code.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.log.info('Click on baseline icon and start time for device'+'${DeviceName}'+':-'  +WDS.sampleResult.getStartTime())
WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//a[@id='baseline-icon-${DeviceName}']")).click()
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
WDS.log.info('Click on baseline icon and end time for device'+'${DeviceName}'+':-' + WDS.sampleResult.getEndTime())

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
```

WDS.log.info('Baseline commit start time for device'+'${DeviceName}'+':-'  +WDS.sampleResult.getStartTime())

```
wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pkg.By.id( "commitToLib"))).click()
wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath( "//*[@id='device-name-${DeviceName}']/../../../../../../..//div[contains(text(),'Manage Library is in progress')]")))
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

WDS.log.info('Baseline commit end time for device'+'${DeviceName}'+':-' + WDS.sampleResult.getEndTime())

The time it is logging for getStartTime() is same in both the case and getEndTime() is same in both the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()` function twice in the same instance of the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/).

I would recommend splitting your actions into 2 WebDriver Samplers, i.e.

- `action 1` should go into WebDriver Sampler 1
- and `action 2` into WebDriver Sampler 2.

WebDriver instance is shared across all WebDriver Samplers so you can basically continue where you left off and from WebDriver perspective it will be no difference.

If you want to have cumulative time of `action 1` and `action 2` in the report - put the relevant WebDriver Samplers under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)